# C# - Creating an overloaded method where one int uses a fixed value and the other receives a value

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to set the value of an overloaded method to 1, but I want the original to remain uninitialised.

```
public void Method1(string string1, decimal decimal1, int int1)
{
}

public void Method1(string string1, decimal decimal1, int int1 = 1)
{
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
>  Error    2   Type 'Application1.Application' already defines a member called 'Method1' with the same parameter types
```

It does not seem to like the `int int1 = 1`. I want `int1` to always equal 1 in the second version of the method, but in the first I want it to receive a user entered value, and so is uninitialised for now.

Sorry if this has been asked before, but after an hour of searching I found no results on what I was looking for. If I am missing anything here, please let me know, I will try to give a better description or the further details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you've got two methods with the same signature. The simplest fix to this is just to remove the final parameter from the second overload, and just call the first overload with a hard-coded value for the last argument:

```
public void Method1(string string1, decimal decimal1, int int1)
{
    // Whatever you actually want to do here
}

public void Method1(string string1, decimal decimal1)
{
    Method1(string1, decimal1, 1);
}
```

(If your two methods aren't meant to achieve the same result, you should give them different names to start with.)

If you want to use optional parameters instead, you can do that by just having *one* method:

```
public void Method1(string string1, decimal decimal1, int int1 = 1)
{
    // Whatever...
}

// Look ma, no second overload
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear enough in the OP. The second version of the method is what will be used if the user does not enter a value for the first, otherwise the user will provide a value. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Moonpenguins: I'm afraid it's still not clear what you mean. Fundamentally you need to choose whether or not you want two overloads - and if you do, you have to give them different signatures.

Comment: Optional Parameter was introduced in c#4.0, please check your c# version before using optional parameter.

Comment: @Nitin: Given that you can still use it when targeting earlier versions of .NET, I wouldn't expect it to be a problem. I doubt that many people are still using VS2008... And the question already contains an optional parameter, so presumably the OP is okay.

Answer (score 7):

Just leave the parameter off of the overload you want the fixed value in and initialize the variable inside the method body:

```
public void Method1(string string1, decimal decimal1, int int1)
{
}

public void Method1(string string1, decimal decimal1)
{
     int int1 = 1;
     //Do things
}
```